# Is it possible to have the characteristics of the genus?

Tags: meshlab

I'm interested by shell morphology and biometrics measurements, especially porosity. Here is a sample of one of my meshes:

[image]

I used `Compute Topological Measures` filter and those are the interesting results:

```
Mesh is two-manifold 
Mesh has 0 holes
Genus is 863
```

I would like to know the surface area, volume and diameter of each genus, is it possible to do it with MeshLab?

Comment: Hi Constance. Did you purposely delete the text of this question? Do you prefer to delete the question itself?

Comment: Hi, yes please I would like to delete the question but I don't know how to do it... I have started a collaboration to help me with this project. Thank you for your answers. Sincerely

Comment: Fine, I will ask an admin to delete it. Good luck with your project

Answer (score 1):

There is not such thing as "volume and diameter of each genus". The [genus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_%28mathematics%29) is an adimensional integer number that summarizes the topology of a surface, and it is independent of the geometry and any distance you can measure in the mesh.

I guess that you probably are interested in the geometry of each *connected component* of the mesh, but can't say from you question. If this is the case, you can use the [split_in_connected_components](https://pymeshlab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filter_list.html#split_in_connected_components) filter to separate one mesh into multiple connected meshes.

You can use two filters to obtain some measures related to the ones named in your question:

- [Compute geometric measures](https://pymeshlab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filter_list.html#compute_geometric_measures) will compute a set of geometric measures of a mesh. Bounding box extents and diagonal, principal axis, thin shell barycenter, vertex barycenter, surface area, volume (for closed meshes).
- [Compute_topological_measures](https://pymeshlab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filter_list.html#compute_topological_measures) will count the number or vertex, edges, faces, unreferenced vertices, boundary edges, connected component(s), holes, and the value for Genus.

One side note: You said that your mesh has a Genus value of 863, which is a quite big number. This is indicative of a very high number of holes or connected components in your input. If this is not an expected value for you, probably you need  to sanitize your input mesh running the filters `remove duplicate vertices`, `remove unreferenced vertices`, `remove zero area faces`, `remove duplicate faces`.